# Probability and combination/permutation help?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

So, I need some help on a few problems. This isn't my homework. I'm preparing for a test and these are just some of the practice problems. I have the answer for them but I don't understand how to get it. I just need someone to explain and show how to get that answer.

Thanks!

Problems:

An experience consists of drawing a ball from a bowl which contains 2 red, 1 yellow, 1 white and 3 blue balls. After noting the color, a second ball is drawn (without replacement) and the color is noted. How many outcomes are there is both balls are the same color?
Answer: 2

A hat contains 4 pieces of paper numbered 1 through 4. If someone draws 2 pieces of paper from the hat without replacement, what is the probability that the two numbers will add up to 4 or less?
Answer: 1/3

A subcommittee of 3 is selected from a committee of 3 men and 7 women. How many ways can the selection be made so that the committee contains both men and women?
Answer: 84

If two 6-sided dice are rolled, what is the probability that at least one of the dice shows a 1?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? Have you tried the problems?

Comment: Yes, I have. 
I looked at the first one again and I get that the answer is 2 because on you can only pick red or blue twice.
The 2nd one, I don't know how to actually go about doing it.
3rd one, I tried finding the outcomes of if all men and all women were selected and subtracted it from the total number of outcomes but that didn't work.
And the last one, I just don't get that one either.
Finding the probability of something is where I get confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain the solutions brief:

**Problem 1**
The only colors for which there are at least two balls are red and blue, so there are only two possible outcomes for the colors of the two balls when they have the same color.

**Problem 2**
The possible outcomes with a sum at most $4$ are only $1+2$ and $1+3$, because $2+3=5>4$. the total number of possibilities is $\binom{4}{2}=6$. Now, we get $\frac 26=\frac 13$.

**Problem 3**
There is exactly one man or there are two men. Adding the number of possibilities for both cases gives:
$$
\binom 31\binom 72+\binom 32\binom71=3\cdot 21+3\cdot 7=3\cdot28=84
$$

**Problem 4**
The probability of the opposite event, i.e. no $1$, is $\left(\frac 56\right)^2=\frac{25}{36}$. Thus, the probability of at least one $1$ is $1-\frac {25}{36}=\frac{11}{36}$.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense now. So, for the second problem, you divide 2 (the only outcomes that are <= 4) by the total number of possibilities, right? And for the last one, you're squaring (5/6) because there are two die, right?

Comment: @Taylor, yes, that is correct. You can only square because the events are independent. Such a thing is not possible for an event like 'at least one $1$'.

Answer (score 0):

The first question should be obvious. The two possibilities are either a red then a red or a blue and a blue. The other colors don't have enough balls.

For the second one, the answer is the chance you won't pick 4 - the chance you will pick 2 and 3.

That is, the ways to choose 2 from the first three balls - the one way to choose 2 and 3, all divided by the total ways to choose 2 balls from 4.$$\frac{\binom{3}{2} - \binom{2}{2}}{\binom{4}{2}} = 1/3$$

The third is the ways to choose 3 from 10 minus the ways to choose 3 from only the women minus the ways to choose 3 from only the men.
$$\binom{10}{3} - \binom{7}{3} - \binom{3}{3} = 84$$

The fourth is 1 - the probability you won't get any 1's, which is $1-\frac{25}{36}$